# How to define operators which contain pluses or minuses only in their symbols, or that have arguments at both side of their names?

Tags: math-operators

I wish to typeset the following two operators:

1. *The increment operator:* My naive attempt was `\newcommand{\Incr}[1]{ #1\!+\!\!+ }`. However, this caused many spacing problems in the sense that the spacing between the two pluses varied in the document, sometimes they were not even ligated. I want a solution that makes the space between the pluses a constant.
2. *The difference relation symbol:* What I want should be clear from `\newcommand{\Diff}[2]{ #1-\!\!-#2 }`. However I face the similar issues here too.

Can you provide a solution to this?

---

**Edit:**

The highlighted in the following images are the intended usage. (The screenshots are taken from Tao's *Analysis I*.)

1. [image: The increment operator]
2. [image: The difference relation symbol]

Comment: you can use mathord +  `{#1}{+}{+}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Why do you write "mathord + ..."? Do you mean to further make `{#1}{+}{+}` an ordinary symbol like `\mathord{{#1}{+}{+}}`? (Is `{...}` the same as `\mathord{...}`?)

Comment: Can you please show some examples of intended usage?

Comment: @egreg The double plus operator is used for the increment operator in the Peano axioms. The difference relation symbol is used to denote the equivalence class of the equivalence relation on naturals that is used to create integers.

Comment: @Atom OK, but that’s not what I asked, that is, some examples of usage. Even a sketch, if not code.

Comment: @egreg I have made an edit. Does it help now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\doubleplus` postfix operator seems just an ordinary symbol, so

```
\newcommand{\Incr}{{+}{+}}
```

is the simplest way to go.

For `\Diff` two minus signs with some negative space between them should be good:

```
\newcommand{\Diff}{{-}\mspace{-9mu}{-}}
```

Try different values of the negative space until you're satisfied.

In context:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Incr}{{+}{+}}
\newcommand{\Diff}{{-}\mspace{-9mu}{-}}

\begin{document}

for instance $3\Incr=4$

where $n\Incr$ actually \emph{redefines}

of the form $a\Diff b$ where

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks tons! This resolves my problem! But can you tell why you enclose minuses and pluses in `{}` in defining the new commands?

Comment: @Atom That serves to tell TeX to forget the nature of the objects and treat them as ordinary symbols; for instance `+` is a binary operation symbol, but `{+}` is ordinary.

Answer (score 0):

For the difference operator, you can use e.g. $A \smallsetminus B$ (`A \smallsetminus B`) or $A \setminus B$ (`A \setminus B`) (both in the `amssymb` package). In general, for binary math operators use `\DeclareMathOperator` (it adds required spacing around it), in `amsmath`.

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator` is definitely not for binary operation symbols.

Answer (score 0):

For the increment operator, you might try `\doubleplus`, from `unicode-math`, `stix` and several other packages.